# Setting a different title on tap as on header of a QDockWidget

Tags: qt, pyside, qdockwidget

I'm currently writing an application in PySide where I want to have multiple DockWidgets available for the user to move around freely.

In the title of my DockWidget I want to have a solid black line and no text, but in the case of having some DockWidgets tabified I want them to show a title on the tabs and only on the tab bar.
For the normal header I used a widget which has just one background color (set in a css file...).
Does anyone know of a simple way to get this done?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Black bar in the Dockheader but no Title in the Tap...]